# perl script only write one row to output file in perl

Tags: perl

i wrote a script to open a file on web, and pull out all rows with wireless in the name.  It writes the out put to a different file, but it only records one line in the output file, should be mulitipe lines.

```
#!\Perl64\eg\perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;

use LWP::Simple;

my $save = "C:\\wireless\\";
my $file = get 'http://dhcp_server.test.com/cgi-bin/dhcp_utilization_csv_region.pl?region=test';

open( FILE, '>', $save . 'DHCP_Utilization_test.csv' ) or die $!;
binmode FILE;
print FILE $file;
close(FILE);

open( F, "C:\\wireless\\DHCP_Utilization_test.csv" ) || die "can't opern file: $!";
my @file = <F>;
close(F);

my $line;

foreach $line (@file) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ m/Wireless /g ) {

        my ($ip,     $rtr,   $mask,    $zip,    $blc, $address, $city,
            $state,  $space, $country, $space2, $noc, $company, $extra,
            $active, $used,  $percent, $extra3, $nus, $construct
        ) = split( /,/, $line );

        my $custom_directory = "C:\\wireless\\";
        my $custom_filename  = "wireless_DHCP.csv";
        my $data             = "$ip $mask $rtr $active $used $percent $nus $construct";

        my $path = "$custom_directory\\$custom_filename";

        open( my $handle, ">>", $path ) || die "can't open $path: $!";
        binmode($handle);    # for raw; else set the encoding

        print $handle "$data\n";

        close($handle) || die "can't close $path: $!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't iterate a file with a `foreach` - you're reading the whole thing into memory to do it. Far better to use `while ( my $line = <F>`. Also: Why are you opening/closing the file each iteration?

Comment: @Sobrique, I wouldn't worry about that, he already has the whole file into memory with the lwp get, having it twice should not be a problem ;)

Comment: The `getstore` function in the same module would prevent the file being in memory.

Comment: @RMax, your code seems unnecessarily convoluted, it can probably be reduced to few lines. What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @TLP, unless there is a special need for saving the original CSV, there is no need for storing a intermediate file: http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/libwww-perl-6.08/lwpcook.pod#LARGE_DOCUMENTS however in this case I suspect that everything could be achieved with `print join map grep split  get`

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is because you're on Windows, but then saving the file using `:raw`, and then reopening it using `:crlf`.

```
open( FILE, '>', $save . 'DHCP_Utilization_test.csv' ) or die $!;
binmode FILE;
print FILE $file;
close(FILE);

open( F, "C:\\wireless\\DHCP_Utilization_test.csv" ) || die "can't opern file: $!";
my @file = <F>;
close(F);
```

I therefore suspect that your `@file` array only contains one line for the entire file.

You can probably also tighten your code to something like the following:

```
#!\Perl64\eg\perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://dhcp_server.test.com/cgi-bin/dhcp_utilization_csv_region.pl?region=test';

my $datafile = "C:\\wireless\\DHCP_Utilization_test.csv";
my $wireless = "C:\\wireless\\wireless_DHCP.csv";

getstore( $url, $datafile );

open my $infh,  '<',  $datafile;
open my $outfh, '>>', $wireless;

while (<$infh>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /Wireless /;

    my ($ip,     $rtr,   $mask,    $zip,    $blc, $address, $city,
        $state,  $space, $country, $space2, $noc, $company, $extra,
        $active, $used,  $percent, $extra3, $nus, $construct
    ) = split /,/;

    print $outfh "$ip $mask $rtr $active $used $percent $nus $construct\n";
}
```